# Neural network for sales revenue prediction

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, references

I'm coding up a neural network without a framework - to predict sales revenue for a shop from product prices.  (Not sure if that is a common approach - as I haven't found any literature on this specific problem.)

After setting up train/test data, I'm finally setting up a simple two layer network (after dismal results with a single layer - which isn't really a NN, I get that).  My understanding is that I should use a linear activation function for the output layer (representing revenue).  Hidden layer is not obvious, but it seems relu as well - although I'm not sure if this makes the model a glorified linear model.

Has anyone experience in this and can point me to a repo or literature?

Comment: Besides that it is not clear what you are actually asking for, just out of curiosity, why not using some framework? It saves you from the tedious and error-prone work of coding all operations and backprop yourself and leaves you free to *actually* perform some experiments with various architectures and activation functions. Also, don't use ReLU for outputs unless you want to get only positive numbers.

Comment: I'll use a framework later - first I'd like to grok a level down.  Yes, ReLU output assumes revenue is always going to be positive (which is is) - I should have stated linear output instead of ReLU, good pick up, I've updated the question.